# How to install pgAgent in greenplum DB?

Tags: greenplum, pgagent

I am trying to install pgAgent. I have installed greenplum. Have't install postgres separately. I am using pgAdmin3. I have downloaded the pgagent3.4.0.
When I am running this **pgagent.sql** file in windows, its redirecting to pgAdmin3 to install the pgAgent schemas. But i am getting the below error :-

```
>>NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pga_jobagent_pkey" for table "pga_jobagent"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "pga_jobclass_jclid_seq" for serial column "pga_jobclass.jclid"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "pga_jobclass_pkey" for table "pga_jobclass"


>>ERROR:  UNIQUE index must contain all columns in the distribution key of relation "pga_jobclass"
********** Error **********

>>ERROR: UNIQUE index must contain all columns in the distribution key of relation "pga_jobclass"
SQL state: 42P16
```

Also i don't have the pgagent extension in my unix server where Greenplum is installed.

How to work accordingly in this type of environment setup?

-- One small question, postgres installation is required separately even if greenplum DB is installed to perform such pgagent activity??

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum doesn't support pgAgent.  Most of the logic is handled by triggers which are not supported by Greenplum.  You should use PostgreSQL if you want to use pgAgent.

Comment: As Jon points out, pgAgent is not supported in Greenplum. What exactly is your use case? Maybe there is another way to solve that problem.

Comment: Can you suggest me such a way?

Comment: You can use cron or if you really needed/wanted to use pgAgent, you can use a PostgreSQL instance dedicated for it.  You can use dblink in PostgreSQL to execute your ETL commands in Greenplum too.